# how to sort List<Object[]>?

Tags: java, arrays, comparator

I need to sort `List<Object[]>` by `Object[3]` value. Is this possible? How does `Comparator` should look like?

I have no idea how to make it now...I have checked this with simple comparator implementation, but it fails..

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you sort `List<Person>` by Persons age?

Comment: simple by comparator overrided compareTo method. but it is not the same. because i have List<Object[]>

Comment: So you've got some code that doesn't work? Please show us that, along with a demonstration of it not working.

Comment: How do you sort by `Object`? Not possible as `Object` has no `compareTo`.

Comment: `Object` does not implement `Comparable`.  Implementing `Comparable` is the conventional way of indicating that a class has a natural order, which is what you're after.

Comment: If you `sort` with your own `Comparator` then you don't need object inside your list to implement `Comparable` (you don't need them to have `compareTo` method). You need to put your logic into `compare(Object[] array1, Object[] array2)` method using value at index `[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple comparator of `Object[]` would look like this. The criterion of comparison will depend on what you are trying to do. And indeed, comparing arrays of objects is not that trivial, and maybe you should try using other data structures for whatever you are trying to achieve. Nevertheless:

```
public class ObjectArrayComparator implements Comparator<Object[]> {
    public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {
        // ...
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Also see [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for more information on how it should behave.

Comment: There's no problem at all. You can use `Collections.sort(Collection,Comparator)` for sorting a list, and it should work right out of the box. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)
Do note that the comparator does NOT sort the object arrays. Rather, it compares two array instances.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to define how you're going to compare your objects, but some way to do it is like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
public class Sorter {

    class Wrapper implements Comparable{
        Object[] array;

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.lang.Comparable#compareTo(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            Object o1 = array[3];

            //replace the code here with the result of the comparison between o1 and o
            //some example here

            return o1.toString().compareTo(o.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sorter s = new Sorter();

        List<Wrapper> list = new ArrayList<Wrapper>();

        Object[] arr1 = new Object[4];
        arr1[0] = "abc1";
        arr1[1] = "def1";
        arr1[2] = "ghi1";
        arr1[3] = new Integer(2);

        Wrapper w1 = s.new Wrapper();
        w1.array = arr1;

        Object[] arr2 = new Object[4];
        arr2[0] = "abc2";
        arr2[1] = "def2";
        arr2[2] = "ghi2";
        arr2[3] = new Integer(1);

        Wrapper w2 = s.new Wrapper();
        w2.array = arr2;

        list.add(w1);
        list.add(w2);

        Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<Wrapper>(){

            @Override
            public int compare(Wrapper o1, Wrapper o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });

        System.out.println(list.get(0).array[3]);

    }

}
```